# How do i run/import a downloaded command-line programm?

Tags: powershell

there is a command-line program called tcpvcon.exe

According to Microsofts website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) it should be possible to access it the following way:

`tcpvcon [-a] [-c] [-n] [process name or PID]`

Do I have to import this executable somehow to be able to access its commands?
I am trying to write a small script, but I am struggling to access the program in a reasonable way that allows me to pass it arguments.

I am using Powershell.

Thanks

Edit:
I downloaded the program, executed it once and accepted the licence agreement. Now I would like to be able to use the above command in Powershell.
If I use it i get following error:
`"tcpvcon" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`...
Do I have to import the cmdlet somhow? I cannot find any information on this... It is probably a very simple fix and I just do not know the procedure.

Thanks again.

Comment: You need to _download it_ first: `Invoke-WebRequest 'https://live.sysinternals.com/tcpvcon.exe' -OutFile 'local\destination\path\to\tcpvcon.exe'`

Comment: What do you mean by "access" it? Do you mean reference it? You would just need to provide the full path (*unless you're in the directory*) of the executable. Then just run the commands as seen.

Comment: Don't forget to [Unblock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file?view=powershell-7.2) the file after downloading

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, tcpvcon is not on a computer unless you download it. Mathias is giving instructions on how to download it.  You can read about tcpvcon here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview

Comment: Thanks for the responses!
I did download it manually and I tried Mathias' command. I also unblocked the file. I still get an error when trying to execute ´´´tcpvcon´´´.
I just want to be able to do it the same way, they did it on the website that I and Darin provided. (Error: "'tcpvcon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"...)